# Get filesize for currentrecord

Tags: php, mysql

I dont know how to use filesize($filename) in this particular code that I need, the problem is I do not know how to represent the filename...

Could someone please tell me what should go after $tblDocs->Value["filesize"]=

```
global $dal;
$tblDocs = $dal->Table("doc_files");
$fileArray = my_json_decode($values["file"]);

for($i = 0; $i < count($fileArray); $i++)
{
$tblDocs->Value["parent_folder_id"]=$_SESSION["current_folder"];
$tblDocs->Value["file_type"]="file";
$tblDocs->Value["file"]=my_json_encode(array($fileArray[$i]));
$tblDocs->Value["hash"]=generatePassword(HASH_LENGTH);
$tblDocs->Value["name"]=$fileArray[$i]["usrName"];
$tblDocs->Value["ownerid"]=$_SESSION["user_id"];
$tblDocs->Value["created"]=now();
$tblDocs->Value["filesize"]=

$tblDocs->Add();

}
```

UPDATE: I have just exported a csv file form my database to see what is actually stored in the file field, and this is result

[{"usrName":"rootcause.jpg","name":"/home/sites/iso-drive.co.uk/public_html/portal/files/rootcause_48zewwp6.jpg","size":1323,"type":"image/jpeg"}]

So...how Do I capture the information in 3rd field "size":1323 - specifically the 1323?

Comment: records don't have "filesizes"

Comment: What is _the current record_? Can you give an example? It isn't clear at all what type of data you are dealing with.

Comment: Please edit your question to post the code. Don't post it in the comments.  Paste the code with original formatting into your question, highlight it and click the `{}` editor button or `ctl-k` to make it a code block.

Comment: Ok I have added the specific code to the edit

Comment: Please post a sample of the result of `print_r($fileArray)`.

Answer (score 0):

Boldly guessing

```
$tblDocs->Value["filesize"]=$fileArray[$i]["size"];
```

Comment: So obvious!!! dont know why I didnt see that before, but for some reason, no its still returning a null value